# In tensorflow, how to gather with indices matching params first dimensions?

Tags: tensorflow

If i have `indices` of shape `(D_0,...,D_k)` and `params` of shape `(D_0,...,D_k,I,F)` (with `0 ≤ indices[i_0,...,i_k] < I`), what is the fastest/most elegant way to get the array `output` of shape `(D_0,...,D_k,F)` with

```
output[i_0,...,i_k,f]=params[i_0,...,i_k,indices[i_0,...,i_k],f]
```

If `k=0`, then we can use `gather`. So, in the past, I had a solution based on flattening. Is there a nicer solution now that tensorflow has matured?

Most of the times, when I want this type of gathering, `indices` is obtained by `indices = tf.argmax(params[:,...,:,:,0])`. For every `(i_0,...,i_k)`, I have `I` vectors of size `(F,)` and I want to keep only those with the maximal value for **one** of the features. A solution which would only work for this special case (a kind of `reduce_max` only using one feature to decide how to reduce) would satisfy me.